# Training Accuracy Score Different From a Follow Up Test Accuracy Scores

Tags: python, tensorflow

Training Accuracy Reported after an accuracy threshold callback is accuracy: 0.8500 but when I go back & test every image with my TestFolder() function I get completely different results, why is that?

```
def TestFolder(TestFolderDir,TestItem):
dir_path = TestFolderDir
Wins=0
Losses=0
for i in os.listdir(dir_path):
    img = image.load_img(dir_path+'//'+i,target_size=(Y_Dimensions,X_Dimensions,3))
    #plt.imshow(img)
    #plt.show()
    X=image.img_to_array(img)
    X=np.expand_dims(X,axis=0)
    images=np.vstack([X])
    val=float(model.predict(images))
    val=round(val)
    #print(val)
    if val==0:
        if TestItem==0:
            Wins=Wins+1
        else:
            Losses=Losses+1 
    if val==1:
        if TestItem==1:
            Wins=Wins+1
        else:
            Losses=Losses+1        
if Wins==0:
    Wins=0.00001
if Losses==0:
    Losses=0.00001
ratio=round(Wins/(Wins+Losses),2)
print("[LTM]["+TestFolderDir+"]Batch Accuracy: ",ratio)
WriteTxt("LTM_BatchAccuracy"+str(TestItem),str(ratio))
```

Comment: Training accuracy is the performance of the model on the training data. Test accuracy is the performance on the test data. Unless though two pieces of data are the same (which they should not be) then you will end up with different results when evaluating each.

Comment: If you have different folder for train and test, you can mix and shuffle and separate the folders for better learning of model across variations. If you have less data try to do Image augmentation and train again. This should give you better result.